# done method "ignored" in beforeEach in mochajs test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a unit test for my wrapper around a web socket client. Here is the code to the test:

```
describe('server', function(){
    var server;
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        server = new Server(function() {
            //try to connect to the server on the expected port
            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
        });

        server.wss.on('connection', function(client) {
            server.wss.close();
            done();
        });
    });
    describe('#server', function(){
        it('starts a server on a given port', function(done) {
            var test = 1;
            test.should.be.ok;
        });
    });
});
```

the issue that i'm running into is that while done is called properly (if i call done a second time right after the first time, i get an error that it was called twice) it does not seem to have any effect. Namely the test will fail after two second with:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
```

I'm kind of new at this, so i probably missed something easy...

Thanks, olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, once you post the question you find the answer.

The trick is to call done inside each of the tests too.

```
describe('server', function(){
    var server;
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        server = new Server(function() {
            //try to connect to the server on the expected port
            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
        });

        server.wss.on('connection', function(client) {
            server.wss.close();
            done();
        });
    });
    describe('#server', function(){
        it('starts a server on a given port', function(done) {
            var test = 1;
            test.should.be.ok;
=====>      done();
        });
    });
});
```